# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.3

Newbie here.  I've been working on a one to many relationship in Laravel 5.4.  I'm working on reading the relationship between User and State.  I keep getting this error.  I have data in the tables.  Here is the view:

```
@foreach ($user->states as $note)

  <li>{{ $note->name }}</li>

@endforeach
```

Here is the User model:

```
class User extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    public function state(){

      return $this->belongsTo(State::class);

    }

    public function role(){

      return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);

    }

    public function district(){

      return $this->belongsTo(District::class);

    }
```

Here is the State model:

```
class State extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'name'
    ];

    public function users(){

      return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get

Comment: ErrorException in a2e15389ecfda07dc83234df296e3ba714f724d9.php line 6:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @foreach ($user->states as $state)

      <li>{{ $state->name }}</li>

Comment: You might be looping over an empty object.

Comment: Just realized I had a typo on the fore each loop in the posting here.  The one above this is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check get results is not a blank `$results != FALSE` You can convert this snippet in laravel way

```
<?php
    if($user->states != FALSE){
        foreach ($user->states as $note){
            echo '<li>'.$note->name.'</li>';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'No Results Found!';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check array or object count before applying foreach loop. It is really a bad practice of using loop without checking the array count.

```
@if(isset($user->states) && count($user->states) > 0)
  @foreach ($user->states as $state)
     <li>{{ $state->name }}</li>
   @endforeach
@else
   No Records Found 
@endif
```

Comment: Because you have no data in the array. Didn't it print out the "No Records Found" ?

Comment: No, it didn't. I can echo all the users.

Comment: can you just print out your results in controller??

Comment: Yes, No records found.

Comment: So it works fine for you. now its upto you, whatever you want to do in case when you have no records in states.

Comment: There are records in states and the users have state_id assigned.